# Gazebo Garden: How to publish the transform of elements in a simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, transform, transforms, rgbd

I need the depth ground truth of a camera view in gazebo and decided to go with an rgbd camera which produces a pointcloud. In order to visualize this I need to somehow publish the transform of the rgbd camera. How can I publish such a transform in gazebo? I can transfer gazebo topics to ros topics with my setup but I don't know how to publish the transforms from the simulation in the first place. Any ideas?

I am working with a gazebo garden setup where I use a gz-ros2 and ros2-ros1 bridge in order to work with ros as well (I know this is not a good setup and the endeavor is to only use ros2 at some point.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the rgbd camera pose through the [pose publisher plugin](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/8b40b546e050ad1e8a3e08897e8146a4869d6d3e/src/systems/pose_publisher/PosePublisher.hh#L35).

See also the [pose_publisher.sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim8/examples/worlds/pose_publisher.sdf) demo world.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer then... ;-)

Comment: Can't upvote yet but accepted it is now.